# Upload file to S3 Bucket. Unable to load Client Side Monitoring configurations from environment variables

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to a S3 Bucket.

My Code:

```
@Configuration
class AmazonConfig {

    @Bean
    fun s3(): AmazonS3 {
        val awsCredentials = BasicAWSCredentials(
            "blabla",
            "blabla"
        )
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
            .withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .build()
    }
}
```

I get a SdkClientException@6820: "com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load Client Side Monitoring configurations from environment variables!"

Answer (score 1):

You can upload files to an Amazon S3 bucket within a Spring App. Here is a multi service example app that uses the AWS SDK for Java V2. Amazon recommends using V2 over V1.

In this example Spring Boot app, the user can select files to upload an Amazon S3 bucket. The photos are then analyzed using the Amazon Rekognition service. Then a report is emailed using the SES service.

[Creating an example AWS photo analyzer application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)